# Take a capture of form

Tags: vb.net, forms

Problem : Form is divided in two parts.

Left side for enter information's. Right side for preview those information's.

On top of form there is a button called Send.

When i click on that button it need to take a snapshot of the right side and send it to email address provided as a attachment.

Solution : Take a snapshot of right side of form and save it to Temp folder 
          - Send a email and attach the file from temp folder 
          - Delete the file ( for any case )
Is it possible to take a ss and convert it to pdf ? is that a better way ?

I found a very helpfull class on forum [Class for Screen Capture](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?385497-Easy-Screen-Capture-Class-Capture-Screen-Desktop-Region-Form-or-Controls)

But is there any way to use method without entering position of the screen.

Example : Right side of form is at GroupBox2 .

Is there any way to take a snapshoot of the groupbox2 on form?

Comment: You have perhaps 2 or 3 questions bundled in there which will not go over well.  All controls, such as a GroupBox have a `DrawToBitmap` method for Step 1 (assuming GroupBox2 is "the right side").  Converting to pdf is Step 2, emailing is Step3, deleting something(?) is Step 4.

Comment: @user3697824 thank you for your answer. My question is how to take a groupbox2 as a snapshoot and save it to local directory. That is only question

Comment: I would think if you changed this line Dim MyWindow As Image = SC.CaptureWindow(Me.Handle)  to pass in the handle of the groupbox instead of the form it would only get the group boxes image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to take a snapshoot of the groupbox2 on form?
>
> and save it to Temp folder

As suggested by user3697824, use [Control.DrawToBitmap()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) with [Path.GetTempFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(GroupBox2.Width, GroupBox2.Height)
    GroupBox2.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), bmp.Size))

    Dim FileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName
    bmp.Save(FileName) ' save it as a Bitmap
    ' < or >
    bmp.Save(FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) ' save it as a Jpeg
    ' *Either way, the file will have the .TMP file extension!
    Debug.Print(FileName)
```